# unique_ptr with Iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, c++, stl, c++11

Does anybody know if it is possible to use the standard unique_ptr with iphone sdk? I have been looking through  and it doesn't seem to exist. Perhaps the gcc version include does not support it yet?.

I know that there are a boost version that emulates the standard behaviour but I would like to use the standard if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Xcode 4.2.  But it won't be enabled by default.  Open your build settings.  You need to choose under "C++ Standard Library", "libc++".  Also the C++03 support for `unique_ptr` is not very good.  To get the best experience also choose under "C++ Language Dialect", "C++0x".

Comment: Is there any noticiable penalty (speed, etc...) by enabling C++11 support? I ask because I don't understand why apple supplied it as default :/. More always is better don't you think?

Comment: Most probably you will see performance increases with C++11 enabled, at least if you are heavily using the std::lib, because move semantics gets enabled.  Compiler defaults are usually conservative.  New stuff is normally not the default until it has been available (via an option) for awhile.

Answer (score 2):

The GCC that ships with Xcode (4.2) does not include C++11 support. Use Apple LLVM 3.0 and you'll get the C++11 support (after enabling it in your C++ Dialect setting)