# std::unique_ptr as a @property in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

How can I define a @property of std::unique_ptr in interface part of objective c class?

```
@property std::unique_ptr<MyClass> ptr;
```

But I can define a shared pointer!

If I define unique pointer then I got error that:

> cannot be assigned because of its copy assignment operator is
>   implicitly deleted

Comment: go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8696263/3733561)

Comment: Thanks .. I did that .. I can use smart pointer in general but just when I'm using unique as a property in the interface section I got this error .. even I use it as a variable it works fine ..

Answer (score 3):

Property synthesis is the culprit here. When you declare `@property unique_ptr<MyClass>`, the compiler implicitly creates setter and getter functions, along with a backing variable.

The set function probably looks something like this:

```
-(void) setPtr:(std::unique_ptr<MyClass>)ptr {
    _ptr = ptr;
}
```

That line in the set function invokes the copy assignment operator of std::unique_ptr which is intentionally deleted because std::unique_ptr uses move semantics. Remember, you can't copy unique_ptr's, you can only transfer ownership from one instance to another.

To get around this problem you either need define your own set and get functions that respect move semantics or you need to work with an ivar directly.

Here's an example set function that would work correctly.

```
-(void) setPtr:(std::unique_ptr<MyClass>)ptr {
    _ptr = std::move(ptr);
}
```

Comment: When the setter is triggered, shouldn't the pointer already copied once as a parameter? Or not?

Answer (score 1):

As Ref[1], compiler will generate setter, getter and instance variable for @property.

---

This following is an example that is compiled without error:

```
// .h file
@interface IOCMixCpp : NSObject
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> mTotal;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly, assign) std::unique_ptr<int> total;

@end
```

```
// .mm file
@implementation IOCMixCpp

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        mTotal = std::make_unique<int>(9);
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setTotal:(std::unique_ptr<int>)total {
    mTotal = std::move(total);
}

- (std::unique_ptr<int>)total {
// This line is error free.
    return std::move(mTotal);

// There is an error in the following line:
// Error: Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::unique_ptr<int>'
//    return mTotal;
}

@end
```

**NOTE:**

unique_ptr SHOULD be used in internal of the Objective-C class and SHOULD NOT declare property with
unique_ptr type.

"Luckily the compiler will prevent you from doing something dumb like declaring a @property with a std::unique_ptr. If it didn’t, the first time you accessed the value using self.foo your class would lose ownership of the pointer." Ref[2]

---

**Reference**

1. Automatic Property Synthesis with Xcode 4.4
   https://useyourloaf.com/blog/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4/
2. Objective C, Encoding and You
   https://medium.com/@dmaclach/objective-c-encoding-and-you-866624cc02de

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think, that `unique_ptr` is a consistent choice for owning a resource in Objective-C. In C++ it's conventional because in C++ members commonly don't outlive their owners (which is a common practice to ease a challenging memory management in the language). Access to such resources are not given through the pointer itself, but with a raw pointer or reference (and this is how you actually say the client code, that it doesn't own the resource):

```cpp
class MyClass {
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<Resource> _res_ptr;
public:
    void setRes(Resource res) {
        _res_ptr = std::make_unique<Resource>(std::move(res));
    }

    Resource& getRes() {
        return *_res_ptr;
    }
    ...
};
```

Owning a resource beyond life of the resource owner is very common in Objective-C however:

```objc
id resource;
{
    TDWObject *owner = [TDWObject new];
    resource = owner.resource;
} // the owner is destroyed here, while the resource keeps on living
```

Moreover, semantic of non-copyable C++ objects cannot be expressed with Objective-C properties in a robust way. Consider the following set of attributes for it:

```objc
@property (assign, nonatomic) std::unique_ptr<Resource> resPtr;
```

It more or less works for setters, but for getters you cannot make a copy of the instance, because copy operations are deleted, and you must not `std::move` the instance from getter, because it would mean that the client code takes away the ownership of the instance from your object. (P.S. making an artificial copy in the getter would violate the class contract). Moreover it imposes limitation of rvalue-references on your property, that is - the client code will have to use either temporaries or cast all lvalues to rvalues to set the data.

---

### Owning a C++ object with `unique_ptr`

What you probably want in reality is to give the client code freedom of passing any type of arguments to the setter (both lvalues and rvalues), and provide access to the property value without altering ownership.

Such a configuration can not be expressed with Objective-C property attributes and I suggest just introducing a pair of custom methods for accessing and setting this data, while owning it with a pointer:

```objc
@implementation TDWObject {
    std::unique_ptr<Resource> _resPtr;
}
...
- (void)setInstance:(Resource)res {
    _resPtr = std::make_unique<Resource>(std::move(res));
}

- (Resource&)instance {
    return *_resPtr;
}

...
@end
```

##### Pros

- **Performance**: neither copying nor moving happen when accessing the data and guaranteed copy elision when setting it (if the client code uses only temporaries).
- **Flexibility**: the client code can pass both lvalues and rvalues to the setter, and you can add any kind of constness (or level of indirection) to the getter.
- **Predicatability**: The reason `unique_ptr` is so popular in C++ also applies here - you can easily predict the lifetime of the resource and be sure it never outlives the owner itself.

##### Cons

- **Dangling Pointer/Reference**: the client code cannot own the resource and should guarantee the owner object to outlive the resource accessed via the getter method. Otherwise the client code ends up with a dangling reference (or pointer) which is not set to `nullptr` automatically.

---

### Owning a C++ object by value

This approach is very straightforward and can be implemented with a synthesised Objective-C property:

```objc
@property (assign, nonatomic) Resource res;
```

##### Pros

- **Simplicity**: you are neither required to implement custom setters or getters, nor have to deal with C++ smart pointers. The object is just copied on both setters (if you don't use rvalues or temporaries) and getters.
- **No dangling pointers**: the client code gets a copy of the data and can own it independently from the owner object.

##### Cons

- **Performance**: this approach is the least effective one. You should be aware that getter is not cheap for this property as it performs copy of user data type (which might not be very complex)
- **Copies everywhere**: You spawn copies on getters and occasionally on setters, so you have to ensure that the copy constructor and copy assignment operator are done right for the class. Also it means that you cannot use this approach for classes with deleted copy operations

---

### Owning a C++ object with `shared_ptr`

I believe this approach is much more consistent in the eyes of Objective-C developers because `shared_ptr` use very familiar concept of reference counting:

```objc
@property (assign, nonatomic) std::shared_ptr<Resource> resPtr;
```

##### Pros

- **Simplicity**: this is a smart pointer, but it works just fine with use of a synthesised Objective-C property.
- **No dangling pointers**: the client code actually owns the resource as long as its `shared_ptr` exists and doesn't need to track lifetime of the owner object.
- **Performance**: this approach is slightly slower than the approach with `unique_ptr` but still very effective, as it doesn't spawn any redundant copies of the resource
- **Consistency**: it works very similar to Objective-C reference counting mechanism and follow familiar rules of strong references (just don't be confused with `assign` attribute of the property).

##### Cons

- **Predicatability**: The main downside is that you cannot predict how long the resource may exist beyond lifetime of the owner, and there is no way to limit it (this, however, is barely considered a downside by an Objective-C developer, where this is default behaviour for properties)