# How to copy class instance (implemented as pImpl) from local variable on stack to memory and set pointer to it

Tags: c++, objective-c, c++14

I am not sure how to do this properly: I have objective-c class with a member variable which is pointer to `MyOtherClass`

```objectivec
@interface MyOtherClass ()
... 
@property (atomic) MyOtherClass* myOtherClassPtr;
...
@end
```

And **I have a factory function which returns instance of `MyOtherClass` by value. I want to copy that value so that the `myOtherClassPtr` points to it.** Is the following code a proper way or there is a better way?

```objectivec
@implementation MyClass
...
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
      auto myOtherClassInstance = Factory::CreateInstance();
      myOtherClassPtr = new MyOtherClass();

      // this line should use copy assignment operator, is that correct?
      *myOtherClassPtr = myOtherClassInstance;
    }
    return self;
}
...
```

Just fyi, `MyOtherClass` is implemented using pImpl and has all special members - header:

```cpp
class MyOtherClass final {
public:

    explicit MyOtherClass();
    ~ MyOtherClass();
    
    // movable
    MyOtherClass(MyOtherClass&& options) noexcept;
    MyOtherClass& MyOtherClass =(MyOtherClass&& options) noexcept;
    
    // copyable
    MyOtherClass(const MyOtherClass&);
    MyOtherClass& operator=(MyOtherClass& options);
   
    ...

private:
    class Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl_;
}
```

implementation:

```cpp
class MyOtherClass::Impl {
  ...
}


MyOtherClass::MyOtherClass() : impl_(std::make_unique<Impl>()) {}
MyOtherClass::~MyOtherClass() = default;

MyOtherClass::MyOtherClass(MyOtherClass &&) noexcept = default;
MyOtherClass& MyOtherClass::operator=(MyOtherClass &&) noexcept = default;

MyOtherClass::MyOtherClass(const MyOtherClass& options)
    : impl_(std::make_unique<Impl>(*options.impl_)) {}
MyOtherClass& MyOtherClass::operator=(MyOtherClass& options) {
    swap(impl_, options.impl_);
    return *this;
}
```

UPDATE1:

better approach (thanks @Jarod42):

```cpp
myOtherClassPtr = new MyOtherClass(Factory::CreateInstance());
```

UPDATE2:

If I use smart pointer instead of raw owning pointer as suggested:

```objectivec
@property (atomic) std::unique_ptr<MyOtherClass> myOtherClassPtr;
```

and initialize it:

```
self.myOtherClassPtr = std::make_unique<MyOtherClass>(Factory::CreateInstance());
```

I get compiler error:

`Object of type 'std::unique_ptr<MyOtherClass>' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted` and `Copy constructor is implicitly deleted because 'unique_ptr<MyOtherClass, std::__1::default_delete<MyOtherClass>>' has a user-declared move constructor`

Which is weird because `MyOtherClass` has explicitly declared copy constructor.

Comment: `myOtherClassPtr = new MyOtherClass(Factory::CreateInstance());` but better to use smart pointer instead of raw owning pointer.

Comment: It seems you are in C++14, as you use `std::make_unique`.

Comment: Thanks @Jarrod42, i am on c++14, but OtherClass is implemented in objective C (iOS wrapper) - implemented liked this:  \@property (atomic) MyOtherClass* myOtherClassPtr; I read on SO that property (as a pointer) in objective c cannot be implemented using unique_ptr because the compiler generates setters and getters and they need copy assignment operator which is implicitly deleted in unique_ptr. (hope got it right) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799048/stdunique-ptr-as-a-property-in-objective-c

Comment: [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is copyable/assignable.

Comment: @Jarod42 you are right, it should work, but i doesn't. I updated the question. I am still doing something wrong...

Comment: You could probably have a private member `std::unique_ptr<MyOtherClass> holder`, and set `myOtherClassPtr = holder.get()`. This way, you'll have the lifetime of the object managed by the smart pointer, while exposing raw pointer to clients.