# Will ObjC setter automatically copy a C++ object passed as a parameter when get called?

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I recently read about a [std::unique_ptr as a @property in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799048/stdunique-ptr-as-a-property-in-objective-c) and the suggestion to store a `unique_ptr` in ObjC as a property is as following:

```
-(void) setPtr:(std::unique_ptr<MyClass>)ptr {
    _ptr = std::move(ptr);
}
```

My question is in ObjC, does the parameter get copied in this case? Because if that happens, `unique_ptr` shall never be declared as a property right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is in ObjC, does the parameter get copied in this case?

That depends. Let me introduce a custom class where all copy operations are removed to better demonstrate possible outcomes under different circumstances:

```cpp
struct MyClass {

    MyClass() {
        std::cout << "Default constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    MyClass(const MyClass&) = delete;

    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&) = delete;

    MyClass(MyClass&&) {
        std::cout << "Move Constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    MyClass& operator=(MyClass&&) {
        std::cout << "Move Assignment" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

};
```

And change the parameter signature of your method accordingly:

```objc
- (void)setInst:(MyClass)inst {
    _inst = std::move(inst);
}
```

---

#### Initialise the parameter with a temporary

Assuming the method in the sample belongs to a class named `TDWObject` the following code will compile just fine:

```objc
[[TDWObject new] setInst:MyClass{}];
```

Under C++17, you will find the default constructor and the move assignment called:

```
Default constructor
Move Assignment
```

The default constructor is called for the temporary, and thanks to guaranteed copy elision, neither copy nor move constructor is needed to initialise the parameter `inst` of the method with the temporary. The move assignemnt is straightforward - it happen when assigning result of `std::move(inst)` operation. If you use C++11 or C++14, standard doesn't guarantee copy elision, but clang will do it anyway. Some compilers use move-semantic instead, but overall for a temporary this code should work just fine.

#### Initialise the parameter with a moved named variable

Another option is to cast any named variable to an rvalue, and it will still allow to initialise the parameter without any issues:

```objc
MyClass inst;
[[TDWObject new] setInst:std::move(inst)];
```

The difference in this case, is that the function parameter will actually call the move constructor without elision optimisation:

```
Default constructor
Move Constructor
Move Assignment
```

#### Initialise the parameter with a named variable

And here is the broken scenario:

```objc
TDW::MyClass inst;
[self setInst:inst];
```

This will not work of course, because the parameter needs to call the copy constructor, which is marked deleted. The good thing about it, this code will never compile, and you will spot the problem straight away.

---

### Considering alternatives

First of all I don't really think that Objective-C properties are compatible with non-copyable C++ classes and decided to give my own answer to the question linked, which you can review [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74487682/5690248).

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect that code to compile as `ptr` is being passed by value there.

Better would be:

```
-(void) setPtr:(std::unique_ptr<MyClass>) &&ptr {
    _ptr = std::move(ptr);
}
```

---

**Edit:** Thinking about it, that might not compile either.  I don't know if Objective_C understands passing parameters by reference, rvalue or otherwise.  But if it doesn't, this should work:

```
-(void) setPtr:(std::unique_ptr<MyClass>) *ptr {
    _ptr = std::move(*ptr);
}
```